# a restaurant [at/on/in] the [road/street/avenue]

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I want to describe the location of the restaurant which I will go with my friends.

a restaurant [at/on/in] the [road/street/avenue]

Which one is correct?

Is there a difference between those sentences?

Comment: I would use _in X Street_; I think of _on X Street_ as mainly American. We don't use _at_ with street names.

Comment: Hmm - I'd go the other way and use `on X Street` rather than `in`.  But maybe I've spent too long talking to Americans :-)  It's different if you include the address: `restaurant X at 39 High Street`